# Making aggregations in two different types and return it grouped in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Having this mapping with two types, `items_one` and `items_two`:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/tester?pretty=true' -d '{
  "mappings": {
      "items_one": {
         "properties" : {
           "type" : {"type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"}
        }},
      "items_two": {
         "properties" : {
           "other_type" : { "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"}
}}}}'
```

I put two items on `items_one`:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/tester/items_one/1?pretty=true' -d '{
    "type": "Bank transfer"
}'

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/tester/items_one/2?pretty=true' -d '{
    "type": "PayPal"
}'
```

... and another two in `items_two`:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/tester/items_two/1?pretty=true' -d '{
    "other_type": "Cash"
}'

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/tester/items_two/2?pretty=true' -d '{
    "other_type": "No pay"
}'
```

How can I make the aggregations in two different fields and return it grouped?

I know I can get it from one field doing:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/tester/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "paying_types": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "type"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

But I cant make it "multi-field" making something like this (which is not working):

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/tester/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "paying_types": {
            "terms": {
                "field": ["type", "other_type"]
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

My desired output should be:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "paying_types" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "Bank transfer",
        "doc_count" : 1
      }, {
        "key" : "PayPal",
        "doc_count" : 1
      }, {
        "key" : "Cash",
        "doc_count" : 1
      }, {
        "key" : "No pay",
        "doc_count" : 1
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it. A script will do the trick:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/tester/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "paying_types": {
            "terms": {
                 "script": "doc['type'].values + doc['other_type'].values"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```